# Android- Connect to server in Thread

Tags: android, multithreading

When I want to connect to server I got ANR message , some solution is to use Thread concept . The following is my code and the app show force close message. Is there something missing in my code

```
public void theardupload()
{
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
              ConnectToServer(url);
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: you should be using asynctask to take away the pain of threading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at Lalit's answer in [Android thread not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546609/android-thread-not-working/7546798#7546798)

Also you must make sure that all exceptions are handled in your ConnectToServer function otherwise the thread will cause an unhandled exception and force close your app